# Regex - Using * with a set of characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm fairly new at regex, and I've run into a problem that I cannot figure out:

I am trying to match a set of characters that start with an arbitrary number of A-Z, 0-9, and _ characters that can optionally be followed by a number enclosed in a single set of parentheses and can be separated from the original string by a space (or not)

Examples of what this should find:

```
_ABCD1E
_123FD(13)
ABDF1G (2)
```

This is my current regex expression:

```
[A-Z_0-9]+\s*\({0,1}[\d]*\){0,1}
```

It's finding everything just fine, but a problem exists if I have the following:

```
_ABCDE )
```

It should only grab _ABCDE and not the " )" but it currently grabs '_ABCDE )'

Is there some way I can grab the (#) but not get extra characters if that entire pattern does not exist?

If possible, please explain syntax as I am aiming to learn, not just get the answer.

ANSWER: The following code is working for what I needed so far:

```
[A-Z_0-9]+(\s*\([\d]+\)){0,1}
# or, as has been mentioned, the above can be simplified
# and cleaned up a bit to be
[A-Z_0-9]+(\s*\(\d+\))?
# The [] around \d are unnecessary and {0,1} is equivalent to ?
```

Adding the parentheses around the (#) pattern allows for the use of ? or {0,1} on the entire pattern. I also changed the [\d]* to be [\d]+ to ensure at least one number inside of the parentheses.

Thanks for the fast answers, all!

Comment: Am not clear about what your requirement is. Do you want to allow `_ABCD1E` and `_123FD(13)` and don't allow `_ABCDE )`? Or do you want to find whether a substring of the input matches the condition?

Comment: Yes, if there are parentheses, they should be surrounding a number. It should also avoid spaces after the initial string if the (#) does not exist.

Comment: there is no need for putting `\d` inside the character class. and `{0,1}` is equivalent to `?`

Comment: That's good to know. I'm assuming ? is only equivalent to {0,1}? Basically, it says that the pattern either exists once or not at all?

Comment: `{0,1}` says the preceding pattern may occur `0` to `1` times. Same is done by `?` which says that the preceding pattern may occur once or do not occur at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex says that each paren (open & closed) may or may not be there, INDEPENDENTLY.  Instead, you should say that the number-enclosed-in-parens may or may not be there:

```
(\([\d]*\)){0,1}
```

Note that this allows for there to be nothing in the parens; that's what your regex said, but I'm not clear that's what you actually want.

Comment: `{0,1}` can be replaced with `?` instead.

Comment: Could you use [\d]+ to force there to be a number inside?

Comment: Aha! That was exactly what I was trying to do. I had tried using [] to surround the statement, but it was obviously not working. Thanks! EDIT: @Feles: I changed the * to be a + and it seems to be working for my tests so far, so I think so.

Comment: I also moved the \s* inside of the parentheses to avoid issues with spaces.

Comment: what's the need of `[]` around `\d`? And this allows empty brackets. @Austin empty brackets are not to be allowed, right?

Comment: My original implementation used [0-9]*, so it is just a fragment from what I had before. I suppose it doesn't do much of anything now that I'm using \d. As far as empty parentheses, I have updated my regex to force a number with [\d]+ since the initial question was asked, which I can can, as you mentioned, just change to \d+.

Comment: I should also add that my original plan was to force a number inside of the parentheses, but I was really just needing a way to use the {0,1} or ? on the entire pattern of (#), which I achieved using the non-escaped parentheses around the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
^[A-Z0-9_]+\s*(\([0-9]+\))?$
```

btw, from your example, the first part accepts not only `[A-Z_]`, but also `[0-9]`

Comment: Ah yes, I made an error when copying the code over. The first part should have been [A-Z_0-9]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job.

```
[1-9A-Z_]+\s*(?:\([1-9]*\))?
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want the following regex:

```
^[A-Z\d_]+(\s*\(\d+\))?$
```

Comment: Looks like the parentheses and the ? are what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used a non-capturing group to avoid grouping matching in results:

```
>>> pattern = r'[A-Z_]+\s*(?:\(\d+\)|\d*)'
>>> l = ['_ABCD1E', '_123FD(13)', 'ABDF1G (2)', '_ABCDE )', 'A_B (15)', 'E (345']
>>> [re.search(pattern , i).group() for i in l]
['_ABCD1', '_123', 'ABDF1', '_ABCDE ', 'A_B (15)', 'E ']
```